# automate extraction of events using REST API endpoint either frequently or in frequent batches

Tags: python-3.x, rest, stream, endpoint

I have an API endpoint for an event store to which I can query a get request and 
 receive a feed of events in ndjson format. I need to automate the collection of these events and store them in a database. As these events are in a nested json structure where some of the events have a complex structure, I was thinking of storing them in a document database. Can you please help me with the options I have in capturing these events and storing them w.r.t. the python libraries/frameworks that I can use to achieve this? To understand the events I was able to use REQUESTS library and get the events. I also tried asyncio and aiohttp to try to get these events asynchronously but that ran slower than requests run. can we create any pipeline using to get these events from the endpoint at frequent intervals?
Also some of these nested json keys have dots, MongoDB is not allowing to store them. I tried CosmosDB as well and it worked fine (only thing there was, if the json has a key "ID", it has to be unique. As these json feeds have ID key which is not unique, I had to rename the dict key before storing into cosmosdb).

Thanks,
Srikanth

Comment: Didn't even read until the end. That's __way__ too broad.

Comment: If I can restrict my ask to know the possible options to automate making frequent get requests (in parallel), can you provide some help?